# How to get detail menu when customer click on any menu?

Tags: android, flutter, dart

I have two APIs, namely Menus and menu details based on Id, when a customer clicks on a menu, what appears is a detail menu, the question is how do you do it so that when a customer clicks on one of the menus, a detailed menu appears that matches the customer's click on that menu? can anyone help me? because I'm stuck

[For Menu Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/yqQai.png) [For the Menu Detail Model](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LTqvd.png) [Menu Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LSV6r.png) [Menu Detail Service](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g0VNQ.png) [Menu or Product Card](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cUwaU.png)

T tried everything like loop or list

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

We have a list of product cards with menus. These menus can be displayed in a user interface using ListView.builder or GridView.builder. When using ListView.builder, each item in the list is wrapped in a GestureDetector or InkWell widget to capture user taps. When a menu item is tapped, we can navigate to a detailed page to show more information about the product. To achieve this, we pass the corresponding product ID (productList[index].idMenu) to the next screen through state. In the detailed page, we can use the initState method to fetch and display specific product details from an API based on the provided ID.